# need clarification on microservices

Tags: microservices

I need some clarifications on microservices.
1) As I understand only choreography needs event sourcing and in choreography we use publish/subscribe pattern. Also we use program likes RabbitMQ to ensure communication between publisher and subscribers.

2) Orchestration does not use event sourcing. It uses observer pattern and directly communicate with observers. So it doesn't need bus/message brokers (like RabbitMQ). And to cooridante all process in orchestration we use mediator pattern.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In microservice orchestration , a centralized approach is followed for execution of the decisions and control with help of orchestrator. The orchestrator has to communicate directly with respective service , wait for response and decide based on the response from and hence it is tightly coupled. It is more of synchronous approach with business logic predominantly in the orchestrator and it takes ownership for sequencing with respect to business logic. The orchestration approach typically follows a request/response type pattern whereby there are point-to-point connection between the services.

In, microservice choreography , a decentralized approach is followed whereby there is more liberty such that every microservice can execute their function independently , they are self-aware and it does not require any instruction from a centralized entity. It is more of asynchronous approach with business logic spread across the microservices, whereby every microservice shall listen to other service events and make it's own decision to perform an action or not. Accordingly, the choreography approach relies on a message broker (publish/subscribe) for communication between the microservices whereby each service shall be observing the events in the system and act on events autonomously.

Comment: It is better use orchestration if there is sequence of actions which should be done and each previous action depends on each other. They are chained. 

If changes should be delevered to multiple places and our current actions do not depends on subscriber states it is better to use choreography.

Comment: The requirement / use case in hand plays a key role in determining the choice between Orchestration and Choreography. Choreography fits well if your requirement is a decentralized architecture whereby each service is aware exactly when to execute its own operations and with whom to interact.  Orchestration fits well for centralized architecture that has  explicit definitions of operations and the order of invocation of services where a central process shall control & co-ordinate the execution of the flow.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Choreography is the one which **doesn't** need persistance of the status of the process, orchestration  needs to keep the status of the process somewhere.

I think you got this somewhat mixed up with implementation details.

Orchestration is called such, because there is a central process manager (sometimes mentioned as saga, wrongly imho) which directs (read orchestrates) operations across other services. In this pattern, the process manager directs actions to BC's, but needs to keep a state on previous operations in order to undo, roll back, or take any corrective or reporting actions deemed necessary. This status can be held either in an event stream, normal form db, or even implicitly and in memory (as in  a method executing requests one by one and undoing the previous ones on an error), if the oubound requests are done through web requests for example. Please note that orchestrators may use synchronous, request-response communication (like making web requests). In that case the orchestrator still keeps a state, it's just that this state is either implicit (order of operations) or in-mem. State still exists though, and if you want to achieve resiliency (to be able to recover from an exception or any catastrophic failure), you would again need to persist that state on-disk so that you could recover.

Choreography is called such because the pieces of business logic doing the operations observe and respond to each other. So for example when a service A does things, it raises an event which is observed by B to do a follow up actions, and so on and so forth, instead of having a process manager ask A, then ask B, etc. Choregraphy may or may not need persistance. This really depends on the corrective actions that the different services need to do.

---

An example: As a practical example, let's say that on a purchase you want to reserve goods, take payment, then manifest a shipment with a courier service, then send an email to the recipient.

The order of the operations matter in both cases (because you want to be able to take corrective actions if possible), so we decide do the payment after the manifestation with the courier.

With orchestration, we'd have a process manager called PM, and the process would do:

1. PM is called when the user attempts to make a purchase
2. Call the `Inventory` service to reserve goods
3. Call the `Courier integration` service to manifest the shipment with a carrier
4. Call the `Payments` service to take a payment
5. Send an email to the user that they're receiving their goods.

If the PM notices an error on 4, they only corrective action is to retry to send the emai, and then report. If there was an error during payment then the PM would directly call `Courier integration` service to cancel the shipment, then call `Inventory` to un-reserve the goods.

With choreography, what would happen is:

1. An `OrderMade` event is raised and observed by all services that need data
2. `Inventory` handles the `OrderMade` event and raises an `OrderReserved`
3. `CourierIntegration` handles the `OrderReserved` event and raises `ShipmentManifested`
4. `Payments` service handles the `ShipmentManifested` and on success raises `PaymentMade`
5. The email service handles `PaymentMade` and sends a notification.

The rollback would be the opposite of the above process. If the `Payments` service raised an error, `Courier Integration` would handle it and raise a `ShipmentCancelled` event, which in turn is handled by `Inventory` to raise `OrderUnreserved`, which in turn may be handled by the email service to send a notification.

Comment: Orchestration - can use simple request/response. There is manager which control process and executes code step by step. If there is an error it reverse process.

Comment: Yes it can, did I say otherwise in my answser? If you're referring to the state I mention here: `the process manager directs actions to BC's, but needs to keep a state on previous operations in order to undo, roll back, or take any corrective or reporting actions deemed necessary`, that still exists in the request response communication, it's just in memory, and if you need resiliency (although for short actions this is less of a problem), you would still persist the in memory state anyway.

Comment: I'll update my answer to reflect the above and make it clear just in case this is what you were referring to.